# Использую Fontello, как заменить префикс icon- на iconF-

Tags: html, css, icon

fontello конфликтует с icoMoon из-за одинаковых префиксов.
Как заменить префикс icon-..... в классе?

Comment: в самом верху есть гаечный ключ - нажмите - там эта настройка

Comment: Спасибо большое